# Error in Django set up

Tags: django, django-urls

How can I set up Django in Window Xp and Ubuntu OS
I finished the step for connection with Database and some problem with connect to admin..
I do it from reading ebook and do it..So there is any easy steps for me..
Please share all idea.

Comment: "Some problem"? **What** problem? If you don't give specific information, you won't get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seem Brett Hayden's [notes on Practical Django Projects](http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/notes-on-practical-django-projects.html)? It contains corrections to errors that crept into the 2nd edition (for Django 1.*) and fills in the missing information.

As for uncommenting the lines in `urls.py` to get Django admin (i.e. remove the hash symbol at the start: `#`), they're the ones that read:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

and

```
(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
```

and

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

plus, in `settings.py` you need to add:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

to the list

```
INSTALLED_APPS
```

Finally, if you need it, Phil Gyford has put the [finished code from the 2nd edition on Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/philgyford/practical-django-projects/src/).